# Restore android google drive backup after factory reset

Tags: restore

I have google drive backup. I am using android 10 on nokia mobile. I did factory reset / erase all data. during set up I skip restore backup.

I check on google drive. I have backup on 23 February. But How do I restore that backup.
I do not find restore backup option on device. I check in setting.

Comment: As far as I know restoring is only provided as part of the setup-wizard after factory reset. See https://support.google.com/android/answer/2819582?hl=en

Comment: On pixel and LG mobile, Under setting devices we can get restore option. But on Nokia and android 10 I am not able to find this option.